# Collection of statements of theorem in Group theory ( without proof, derivation )

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

Guiseppe Peano, who devised an efficient symbolic language and sought
to provide, with his 'Formulario Mathematico'
wrote an encyclopedia of **all known formulas and theorems of mathematics.**

**Is there  a book/document/paper that contains  all (or important)  known formulas,theorems (compilation of statements of theorem without proof, derivation ) in  Group theory ?**

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such a thing, the field is way too big for that.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like what you're asking for (an encyclopedic reference) is basically what the [*Handbook of Algebra*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1570795496800039) series provides. They cover group theory.

It is probably the largest collection of interesting theorems in one place, though I doubt any such collection could be totally comprehensive. That sounds like an impossible task.

Otherwise I think you're stuck doing what everyone else does: read textbooks and stitch together an atlas of results that are useful for you to use.

Comment: I've not found anything better than this (volume 2) so far, but it also misses my requirement, I have been informed just now  Ramanujan story of having a book of theorems, formulas only, I am looking for something like that.

Answer (score 3):

[Nicolas Bourbaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolas_Bourbaki) is the collective pseudonym under which a group of (mainly French) 20th-century mathematicians, with the aim of reformulating mathematics on an extremely abstract and formal but self-contained basis, wrote a series of books beginning in 1935. With the goal of grounding all of mathematics on set theory, the group strove for rigour and generality. Their work led to the discovery of several concepts and terminologies still used, and influenced modern branches of mathematics.

While there is no one person named Nicolas Bourbaki, the Bourbaki group, officially known as the Association des collaborateurs de Nicolas Bourbaki (Association of Collaborators of Nicolas Bourbaki), has an office at the École Normale Supérieure in Paris.

See for example http://www.cmat.edu.uy/~marclan/TM/Algebra%20i%20-%20Bourbaki.pdf

Comment: @mikeSQ This is a good reference, despite age and despite the fact that it contains proofs (contrary to the original request.) Neither one should prevent you from using them, though.

Comment: @rschwieb no its not, though, I've not gone through the text  properly, anyway , thanks NH, and +1.